# Analog Clock using swift

Tags: ios, swift, clock

I'm trying to create a simple analog clock using swift. I aim to rotate the UIimage based on the time. 6 degrees a second for the second hand. 6 degrees a minute for the minute hand, and 30 degrees an hour + minutes. How would you go about doing this?

I'm new to coding, and have found [some obj-c examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092513/24-hour-analog-clock), but I'm not sure how to convert it over into swift and which things I should be calling.

Any help is always greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to SO.  Unfortunately your question is too broad.  You should ask specific questions, showing what you have attempted and your specific problems.   Please see "how to ask" in the help centre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How would you go about doing this

I would do it by drawing the hands of the clock each in its own layer and then using a rotation transform to rotate each of the layers (the hands) independently the required amount, with the center of the clock as the anchor point, in response to different repeating NSTimers that would notify me when it's time to move each hand.

Comment: Not very different from my compass arrow example here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch04p148layerAnimation/ch17p490layerAnimation/ViewController.swift

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an analog clock demo app in Objective-C when iOS 7 came out to test out the spring physics that were added with that version.

It's not in the language you're after, but it does everything you're asking for. It would be a good exercise to take the app and convert it from Objective-C to Swift.

Here's the link: [**ClockAnimation project on Github**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/ClockAnimation.git)

My project uses a custom subclass of UIView called WTClockView. The clock view contains a subview and views for hour, minute, and second hands. The clock hands are connected to the clock view with outlets